# iOS7 - AutoRotate is not getting invoked

Tags: iphone, ios7

Team,

I am working on a support project and I have basic knowledge on iPhone. When I change the Orientation in my device, none of the below methods gets invoked at the time of Orientation change.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        // your code for portrait mode

    }

    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    //return here which orientation you are going to support

}
```

I am pushing the screen through presentViewController and above methods gets invoked before pushing the screen, but nothing after the screen is pushed and when I change the orientation.

Also, I tried creating a Category as explained below, but I am getting viewController not found error, not sure what I am missing here...

In IOS7.If you use a UINavigationController, the rotate processing way is different!

See UINavigationController, can see it is a subclass of UIViewController, then that is in him there are listed in the above the rotation of the processing method; So wo need to use UINavigationController also do rotate processing,

My way is to add a Category to UINavigationController, do so.

In the Category. M writes

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {    
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {    
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation]; 
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For me the other two functions are also working but you can try to use the delegates below

From Apple Docs:

> Sent to the view controller just before the user interface begins
>   rotating.
>
> ```
> - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
> ```
>
> duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
>
> Sent to the view controller after the user interface rotates:
>
> ```
>  -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
> ```